# Ray seems to be caching the imported .py even after code terminates

Tags: python, import, ray

I am testing ray on 1 head node and 1 cluster node.
I started the head node with:

```
ray start --head --redis-port=6379
```

and the cluster node with:

```
ray start --address='<ip_head_node>:6379'
```

At both the head node and the cluster node, there is f.py & ray_test.py

f.py:

```
def f(num):
    print("f:", num)
    return num
```

ray_test.py:

```
import ray
import f

@ray.remote
def r(num):
      return f.f(num)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_tasks = 8
    ray.init(address="auto")
    result_ids = [r.remote(t) for t in range(num_tasks)]
    results = ray.get(result_ids)
    print(results)
```

running:

```
python ray_test.py
```

works fine.

But, when I modify f.py, (eg. change the print statement), on BOTH head and cluster node, (both head node and cluster node have the same f.py because I'm rsync-ing it over and also verifying on the cluster node), subsequent:

```
python ray_test.py
```

still uses the **OLD** f.py

I've even tried deleting f.py on the cluster node, but the code still runs when it shouldn't (??) So it seems that f.py is being cached somewhere? Or am I missing something?

I've since narrowed it down to using either

```
ray.init()
```

which will reload f.py each time, but does not run on the cluster, or

```
ray.init(address="auto")
```

which will seems to use a cached version of f.py, and will not reload new versions of it, despite subsequent executions of ray_test.py, but does run on the cluster.

My goal is to be able to modify f.py on head node, rsync it to the cluster node, and run ray_test.py using the NEW f.py, without stopping and restarting ray on both head and cluster. Is that possible, or is that not the correct workflow with ray?

Thanks!

Python 3.6.9, ray==0.8.5

Answer (score 0):

This will be handled at this post instead. https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/8550